# Поиск самого частого слова в тексте

Tags: python

Тут такая задача:

Напишите программу, которая считывает текст из файла (в файле может быть больше одной строки) и выводит самое частое слово в этом тексте и через пробел то, сколько раз оно встретилось. Если таких слов несколько, вывести лексикографически первое (можно использовать оператор < для строк).

Слова, написанные в разных регистрах, считаются одинаковыми.

И вот собственно мое решение:

```
def getkey(value):
for key, v in d.items(): #нахождение ключа для вывода слова в ответе
    if v == value:
        return key

g = 'TZccc cUcYp dc XTpZaUpX XTpZaUpX XTpZaUpX XTpZaUpX XTpZaUpX ZXppTYTZ YTbd dcZaX U bpXUaTTdc TZccc XTpZaUpX dcZaX pbUbaaY c dc XYXppTXTX adc dc daTXcZUUd XcbU UU XTpZaUpX aYaZ cTTTb bX daTXcZUUd UcU aYXcXYcUp bT X adc daTXcZUUd TdUUdYTb a pZdbUaYXd UcU daTXcZUUd UU pbdZTcUpa b Yc Xpdb UYUYZ dYcZ aYXcXYcUp pU pbUbaaY UU XX XX adbXTYUZa aTXa aTXa dY cYaYZUZ ddXYcX dXcbUXcX dadTT XX dadTT aTXa TYpZ XX bTdbdYU dY bZ bTdbdYU dccYpcYTU UZ bdTppTTT cc XadTYaaXT cc pad a cc cc cc cc TUZaZ Z cc cc TZbUdYbYZ cc cc cZpTa ddpdcUU pTXY aTddpZdpX cU bU apa TdZbXYcZ ZcTT cc UbbTTcUpU ZbbXUpX dpdUppcTZ aTddpZdpX ZZXbp cU cUUpUpd YbZZdppU ZXa Z UUpd caUbZ Uc dXZYdT ZZppUaYap XYc ZT TUTZcYbUp XYc dXZYdT TpXTaU U XYc ZZppUaYap dZXa cbX Z TUTZcYbUp paUbXUX Td YbadcpZ YdaUZUaY dYdbXaUbd bbXX Td bUpXXcad TpTbYcpcX XYc pYXpapYZa dY aTXp dZXa YUTbZZX dY XYc dY aUYU acYdZYdc YUTbZZX cTTYcppY ZXcddpU dXZYdT UZ Xad XZZ TpXTaU YUZYbX cpZbZc YUa ZZppUaYap aZTbYdd YcpcZpbpT bTp U Yc dZ baUYdZXU dZ dZ bYacba ZdTaZXdX dZ dZ XpYT pT YcXZaa baUYdZXU aappXT Tbpdb pcYXddpbp a XZUaTT baUYdZXU ZcdaUYdXb Tbpdb baUYdZXU bTU cd baUYdZXU dacZ aappXT bdpZYba Uc dZ UYbYdTpY T dbUTcZcTX UYbYdTpY Y TabbUbcXb bTU dXUX aa cd dZ a Tbpdb ZppXpYX pYb pZa pZa ZcT ZcT ZcT UaXadZc cZdYYY cZdYYY cZdYYY dcUd dYZd ppZZb XcdYa aZdpX XUdp dYZd babTUpZXb YYbTXZbb cZdYYY XpbUTdUX cdaTTT ZcdZXaa pZXZaXbT UUdTUUaU XUdp UTYcbZd cZdYYY'

s = g.lower().split(' ')

d = dict()
a = 0

for i in s:
if i in d.keys():
    d[i] += 1             #добавление в список слов и подсчет их повторений
else:
    d[i] = 0

for j in d.values():
if j > a:              #нахождение самого большого количества повторений
    a = j

print(getkey(a), a)
```

*Для справки: в переменной g данные, которые находятся в специальном файле.

Так вот, код почему-то работает неверно и выдает 'cc 10' вместо 'czdyyy   11'. Требуется помощь более опытного кодера.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ошибка в том, что когда вы подсчитываете слова, вы записываете *0* вхождений, в случае, когда этого слова еще нет в словаре. Но ведь если слово нашлось первый раз, то оно уже появилось *1*, а не *0* раз. Записывайте *1* вместо *0*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. считать строку
2. разбить на слова
3. перевести слова в нижний регистр
4. воспользоваться функцией collections.Counter (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)

Касательно вашего кода:

```
for i in s:
    if i in d.keys():
        d[i] += 1             #добавление в список слов и подсчет их повторений
    else:
        d[i] = 0
```

вот тут ошибка - первый раз когда слово встречается вы создаете запись в словаре, НО СО ЗНАЧНИЕМ 0, а надо со значением 1, ведь первый раз тоже надо подсчитать слово, а вы его не считаете

```
for i in s:
    if i in d.keys():
        d[i] += 1             #добавление в список слов и подсчет их повторений
    else:
        d[i] = 1
```

вообще можно для таких целей пользоваться методом `get`:

```
for i in s:
    d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1
```

т.е. получаем значение по ключу и прибавляем 1, а если значения нет, то вернутся 0

Отсортировать можно вообще было бы так:

```
res = sorted((c, v) for v, c in d.items())[-1]
```

Т.е. без использования Counter код мог бы быть таким:

```
d = dict()

for i in g.lower().split(' '):
    d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1

res = sorted((c, v) for v, c in d.items())[-1]

print(res[0], res[1])
```

Хотя оптимальнее использовать функцию max:

```
res = max((c, v) for v, c in d.items())
```

поскольку выполнять сортировку - избыточно

А вообще задачу можно выполнить так:

```
count, word = max((c, v) for v, c in collections.Counter(g.lower().split(' ')).items())

print(count, word)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Учту все замечания.